# How can I connect to a git repository and work from it remotely cross-platform?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, cross-platform

I am trying to build an update sequence for my game server. I am using git to host my file platform changes since it is capable of merging.

First, I want to create a repository and upload it to my git account as a 'fresh install'.

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/...
git add "RV SERVER"
git commit -m "Initial upload"
git push
```

This now uploads my server from my development PC. I now want to download the git repository on my VPS via SSH.

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/...
git pull
```

Then when I want to update the server files with any new player saves I use this

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/...
git commit -m "Merge for any player save updates"
git push
```

However, I get the error that there is a pull request waiting (which is the update) however, I want to first save the player information so it merges with the new update and then download any file updates.

How can I do this?

Comment: Player saves should go in a database, not in git.

Comment: You're right! However, my VPS is running R-Pi 3 Kali OS and the SQL is just messed so I'm running in SQL-disabled for now - it is a localhost game anyway and contains no sensitive data plus my git repo is private but thanks for raising your concern! @Tanktalus